# Unauthorized client when requesting Docusign authorization code through Postman

Tags: oauth-2.0, postman, authorization, docusignapi

I have imported the docusign api into Postman through the following URL: https://developers.docusign.com/tools/postman/

However, when trying to request an authorization code I am getting the following error:

{
"error": "invalid_grant",
"error_description": "unauthorized_client"
}

I have created an API app in the docusign admin settings and have an integration key and URI.

I have used the following URL to request the authorization code:

https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/auth?response_type=code&scope=signature&client_id=**INTEGRATIONKEY**&redirect_uri=http://localhost/

I expected to receive an authorization code but I am only getting an unauthorized client error.

I have read all articles but I just can't seem to get this working unfortunately...

Answer (score 1):

Note that Auth Code Grant has 2 parts:

First part you use the URL like the one you posted - response_type=code&scope=signature&client_id=**INTEGRATIONKEY**&redirect_uri=http://localhost/

This above URL is not an endpoint of an API, you paste it into the browser, you may need to login with user/password, you may need to obtain consent, and you then get redirected to where you want with some URL parameteres,

That gives you back a "code" which is **not yet** an access token.

Then you have to make an API call, which is in the postman collection at the very top:

If all env parameters are set in postman, and you manually copy/pasted the code in here, this should work just fine.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I did not enter the generated BTOA() code in the header under the key "Authorization".